# VNC not installing in ubuntu 12.04.5 LST

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I am trying to install VNC server though `putty`, but it is not getting installed.

I have run following command to install

1. `sudo apt-get install gnome-core`
2. `sudo apt-get install vnc4server`
3. `vncserver`

I am getting the below error, what is causing this?

```
msfl@chanakyauat:~$ sudo apt-get install vnc4server
[sudo] password for msfl:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
The following extra packages will be installed:  
  libfontenc1 libfs6 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libllvm3.0 libutempter0 libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-shape0 libxfont1 libxkbfile1 libxmu6 libxtst6
  libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xbase-clients xbitmaps xfonts-base xfonts-encodings
  xfonts-utils xinit xterm  
Suggested packages:  
  libglide3 vnc-java mesa-utils nickle cairo-5c xorg-docs-core xfs xserver xfonts-cyrillic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfontenc1 libfs6 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libllvm3.0 libutempter0 libx11-xcb1 libxaw7 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-shape0 libxfont1 libxkbfile1 libxmu6 libxtst6
  libxv1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 vnc4server x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xbase-clients xbitmaps xfonts-base
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xinit xterm  
0 upgraded, 32 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.3 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 62.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y  
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libglapi-mesa libx11-xcb1 libxcb-glx0 libxxf86vm1 libgl1-mesa-glx libllvm3.0 libxmu6 libxaw7 libxcb-shape0 libxkbfile1 libxtst6 libxv1 libfontenc1 libfs6 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libutempter0 libxfont1 libxxf86dga1 x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-utils x11-xfs-utils x11-xkb-utils x11-xserver-utils xinit xbase-clients vnc4server xbitmaps
  xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils xfonts-base xterm   
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libglapi-mesa amd64 8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7  
  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)  


Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxxf86vm/libxxf86vm1_1.1.1-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-glx_8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/llvm-3.0/libllvm3.0_3.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxmu/libxmu6_1.1.0-3_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxaw/libxaw7_1.0.9-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxcb/libxcb-shape0_1.8.1-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxkbfile/libxkbfile1_1.0.7-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxtst/libxtst6_1.2.0-4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxv/libxv1_1.0.6-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libfontenc/libfontenc1_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libfs/libfs6_1.0.3-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dri_8.0.4-0ubuntu0.7_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libutempter/libutempter0_1.1.5-4_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxfont/libxfont1_1.4.4-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libx/libxxf86dga/libxxf86dga1_1.1.2-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-apps/x11-apps_7.6+5ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-session-utils/x11-session-utils_7.6+2_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-utils/x11-utils_7.6+4ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-xfs-utils/x11-xfs-utils_7.6+1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-xkb-utils/x11-xkb-utils_7.6+4_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/x11-xserver-utils/x11-xserver-utils_7.6+3_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xinit/xinit_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg/xbase-clients_7.6+12ubuntu2_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vnc4/vnc4server_4.1.1+xorg4.3.0-37ubuntu4_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xbitmaps/xbitmaps_1.1.1-1_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xfonts-encodings/xfonts-encodings_1.0.4-1ubuntu1_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xfonts-utils/xfonts-utils_7.6+1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xfonts-base/xfonts-base_1.0.3_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xterm/xterm_271-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?    
msfl@chanakyauat:~$ vncserver        
No command 'vncserver' found, did you mean:   
 Command 'vnc4server' from package 'vnc4server' (universe)   
vncserver: command not found    
msfl@chanakyauat:~$    
msfl@chanakyauat:~$ vnc4server    
The program 'vnc4server' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install vnc4server
```

Comment: `Install these packages without verification [y/N]? T`... T is not an answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your system reports that:

```
Something wicked happened resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

followed by a mass of `Failed to fetch` showing the same error for both that host name as well as `security.ubuntu.com`.

The host name `us.archive.ubuntu.com` resolves for me, to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses (technically `A` and `AAAA` DNS RRs).

Since the URLs themselves look sane, I am inclined to think that the `:http` tacked on is an artefact of how `apt-get` displays host names in the case of failure, rather than an actual part of the host name it is trying to connect to.

Hence, I am inclined to believe that your problem lies *somewhere other than VNC*. Specifically, I believe that **your problem lies in DNS resolution in general.**

**Fix your name resolution** settings, and `apt-get` should start working too. That should allow you to install both VNC as well as the apparently much needed security updates to your system.

Answer (score -1):

But in the last line of the output of your system log reports that the program can not find the "vncserver" and offers to use vnc4server.
Just try:

```
msfl@chanakyauat:~$ vnc4server
```